Cannot animate component when mounting it
Goal: Very simply, given a state showStupid, I want to mount/show a <StupidComponent /> when showStupid===true.
Also, I would prefer to use useAnimate if possible. I tried following based on the example of their website: https://www.framer.com/motion/use-animate/##exit-animations
// StupidComponent.tsx

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useAnimate } from 'framer-motion'

export function StupidComponent() {
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate() // Define the animation scope

  useEffect(() => {
    // When the component is mounted, animate to the final state
    animate(
      scope.current,
      {
        scale: 1,
      },
      {
        duration: 0.5, // Animation duration
        ease: 'easeInOut', // Animation easing
      }
    )

    return () => {
      // When unmounting, no animation needed
      // Set the default scale explicitly without triggering animation
      if (scope.current) {
        scope.current.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)' // Default scale
      }
    }
  }, [animate, scope])

  return (
    <div ref={scope} className="p-4 bg-orange-400 text-white">
      This component scales to 1 when it appears.
    </div>
  )
}

// App.tsx
import { useState } from 'react'
import { StupidComponent } from '@/components/StupidComponent'

export const App = () => {
  const [showStupid, setShowStupid] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setShowStupid((prev) => !prev)
        }}
      >
        Show stupid
      </Button>
      {showStupid && <StupidComponent />}
    </>
  )
}

Currently, when I click the button, the component shows up without animation

have you tested to make sure that the element does not start at scale 1.0, therefore animating from scale 1.0 to scale 1.0?

@dqhendricks I tried setting scale: 1 on the animate() call, and it actually animates correctly scaling from 1 to 1.5. So the issue is that it's not setting the initial state to 0.5 indeed... not sure how to do it. I'm using tailwind, scale-50 did not work

I'll be honest, I've never used this animation library before, so am not sure, but I think you at least have the clue you need to figure this out now with a little experimenting/researching.

So there is some CSS stuff you could do to animate the scale entrance. But if you'd like to keep it all within framer-motion, the docs have some info on animating entrances. You could probably do it without the useAnimate hook, but if you wanted to keep that you should set the div to be motion.div inside of the StupidComponent. Then you can give it an initial value before the animate is ran.
function StupidComponent() {
  const [scope, animate] = useAnimate() // Define the animation scope

  useEffect(() => {
    // When the component is mounted, animate to the final state
    animate(
      scope.current,
      {
        scale: 1,
      },
      {
        duration: 0.5, // Animation duration
        ease: 'easeInOut', // Animation easing
      }
    )

  }, [animate, scope])

  return (
    <motion.div initial={{scale: 0.5}} ref={scope} className="p-4 bg-orange-400 text-white">
      This component scales to 1 when it appears.
    </motion.div>
  )
}

However, you could remove the useAnimate and simplify this further to just something like this, where we set the desired animation in the div.

function StupidComponent() {


  return (
    <motion.div initial={{scale: 0.5}} animate={{scale: 1}}  className="p-4 bg-orange-400 text-white">
      This component scales to 1 when it appears.
    </motion.div>
  )

